# JSON to Specific XML format convertion in Web API

Tags: asp.net, json, xml, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core

I am going to build a Web API in ASP.Net Core,which Consist of Multiple external Api Calls.
My Api take the request and response as "JSON".But some External Api's only works with XML.Now,I am stuck with converting json to XML in an Api Scenario.More details as follows:

My Api Recieving Request as (Json):

```
{
  "Credential":"mrtest:testpw123,
  "BookId": 6,
  "BookName": "XXX",
  "BookAuthor": "yyy yyy",
  "BookPrice":512
}
```

And I want to Post this same information to an External Api as:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:tns="http://kkr.eu/" xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soap:Header>
<tns:Credential xsi:type="tns:CredentialPro">
<tns:UserName>mrtest</tns:UserName>
<tns:Password>testpw123</tns:Password>
<tns:UserID>4</tns:UserID>
</tns:Credential>
</soap:Header>
<soap:Body>
<tns:AddBookDetails>
<tns:BookId>6</tns:BookId>
<tns:BookName>XXX</tns:BookName>
<tns:BookAuthor>yyy yyy</tns:BookAuthor>
<tns:BookPrice>512</tns:Price>
</tns:AddBookDetails>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

So I want to Convert Json to XML in above Format.
Is there Any way to do this Simply?
How I Build "tns:UserName,tns:BookId,.." Like tags from Json??
Also Confused About Namespaces including in XML tags.

As I am beginner on Web API Hope you guys Help me..

Comment: The entire point of SOAP is that you *don't* build this XML manually. A SOAP framework will do all of this for you. In your own code all you do is call methods and pass arguments. So before you waste your time figuring out how to build this XML, read up on how to get a SOAP client running in ASP.NET Core, how to consume the WSDL that the remote endpoint provides to create a local API for you, and how to invoke the methods of that API in your code. This looks like a good starting point for reading: https://stackify.com/soap-net-core/

Comment: Search for Content Negotiation in web api, and you come to know that you don't have to do anything, Web api will do for you everyting.

Comment: @Tomalak Thanks.. When i refer the information regarding this,all readings are showing to add a service reference  to the project.I am looking for the solution rather than adding a service reference to my Project.Is any way??